# How can I move (animated) UICollectionView cells in and out of a circular shape [PICS]

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am using a custom layout to position my UICollectionViewCells like so:

[image]

This works great. Now, when I press the button in the bottom-left corner, I would like to have all of the cells animatedly return to the center of the view, like so:

[image]

I kind of have this working, but it isn't animating at all. It just kind of pops in that way. Here is the code I am using for the reload action:

```
- (IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
} completion:nil];
}
```

And in my layout class, I have a flag that I am flipping each time prepareLayout is called that adjusts the center of the cell in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*) layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZEw, ITEM_SIZEh);

if (self.isCircle) {
    attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius *
                                cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount),
                                _center.y + _radius *
                                sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount));
} else {
    attributes.center = [self collectionView].center;
}

return attributes;
}
```

How can I animate the cell's movement back to the center of the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found my answer. Make a different layout and switch to it with an animation:

```
[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:home animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put the changes in a UIView animation like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
   if (self.isCircle) {
       attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius *
                                cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount),
                                _center.y + _radius *
                                sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount));
   } else {
       attributes.center = [self collectionView].center;
   }
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but no dice. Still no animation.